# Ensure graceful scale down with PCF Autoscaler

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, autoscaling

I have a PCF spring boot application, which handles some long running batches, and planning to use PCF AutoScaler for automatic scaling.

How to ensure graceful scale-down if app takes approx 15-20 minutes to drain already running jobs? Is there any mechanism to control scale down time so that app instance gets enough time before it's shut down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of time an application has to gracefully shutdown is set by the platform, not by PCF Autoscaler or your application. With PCF it is going to default to 10 seconds.

> By default, apps must finish their in-flight jobs within ten seconds of receiving the SIGTERM before TAS for VMs terminates the app with a SIGKILL.

https://docs.pivotal.io/application-service/2-12/devguide/deploy-apps/app-lifecycle.html#shutdown

As noted at that link, you can change that value but it's platform-wide.

> To modify the timeout period on the TAS for VMs tile or IST tile, go to the Advanced Settings tab and edit the “app graceful shutdown period” property.

There are downsides to changing it, like longer evacuation times when updating Diego Cells. You're essentially giving all of your applications that much time to run before the platform can stop the application, which ties up platform resources for longer periods of time.

I would not recommend increasing the value platform-wide to accommodate your need of 15-20 minutes.

My suggestion would be to adjust your batch jobs such that they can be paused or stopped and resumed later. When the SIGTERM is sent, you can then tell the jobs to pause or stop, which can hopefully be done in less than 10 seconds. When your application restarts, the paused or stopped job can be resumed.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for clarification! Follow up question- Is it possible to customize autoscaler's scale-down operation, or add hooks to it like AWS EC2? E.g. instead of sending SIGTERM, invoke custom operation to e.g. shut down instance in custom manner?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The PCF Autoscaler is not what sends those signals. The platform sends the signals when an application is stopped. When you scale up/down with PCF Autoscaler, the Autoscaler is just basically doing `cf scale -i` and changing the instance count. That in turn either starts or stops new instances, so the only shutdown hook is catching the SIGTERM that is sent when an app is stopped.

Comment: Do you know in which order auto-scale down happens? i.e. random instance/newest instance first/oldest instance first?  Because a thought i am having is if scale down sequence is known, maybe one can think of flushing up all jobs from that instance in advance and provide scale down signal to autoscaler using some custom metric?

Comment: It's not specific to Autoscaler. It's issuing what amounts to `cf scale -i` so it would depend on which one the system takes. I don't know if that behavior is consistent, sorry.